# How do I cancel an Indian visa in order to be able to apply for OCI?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens

My daughter is a foreign national of Indian origin and has multiple-entry Indian visa valid until 2017. How I cancel that visa in order to be able to apply  Overseas Citizenship of India (OCI) for her?

Comment: Do you mean that she has a multiple-entry visa? What is OCI? Is your daughter an adult?

Comment: Right now, your question is very difficult to understand. What's your citizenship and what is your daughter's? Where are you resident? Are you applying for OCI for yourself or are you applying so your daughter will get OCI?

Comment: Her question is not that difficult to understand, but is not really travel related, as it is about pseudo-citizenship.

Comment: I agree with Tom, vote for reopening.

Comment: How old is your daughter? If she isn't a minor, you probably can't do anything to cancel that visa.